# HTTP response status code for lack of params in the request

Tags: http

I have an URI, that is available by POST.
It *requires* 4 POST params.

What HTTP response status code should I use if user doesn't pass me all the required params?

406?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use 400 instead of 406:

> 406 Not Acceptable The requested resource is only capable of
>   generating content not acceptable according to the Accept headers sent
>   in the request.[2
>
> 400  Bad Request The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax.[2]

[List of HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Also, you can generate an `Exception` that would be better since you can write a custom error that indicates what is wrong with the request.

Comment: The problem is 406 should have incorrect headers. POST params are not in headers. 400 should have syntax error in HTTP. So these 2 codes are not good for the problem.